# How to set Powered property of /org/bluez/hci0 using sd_bus_set_property?

Tags: dbus, bluez

Recently I started to develop a bluetooth app using API exposed via D-BUS. After some research, I chose to use sd-bus library to communicate with D-Bus.
Here is my code:

```
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>

sd_bus* bus_;
if (sd_bus_open_system(&bus_) < 0)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("sd_bus_open_system");
}
sd_bus_error sd_error;
bool powered = true;
if (sd_bus_set_property(bus_,
    "org.bluez",
    "/org/bluez/hci0",
    "org.bluez.Adapter1",
    "Powered",
    &sd_error,
    "b", &powered) < 0)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Bluetooth Power On");
}
```

The code above throws "Bluetooth Power On" and the return value of `sd_bus_set_property` is -22 (EINVAL). I couldn't make much sense from `sd_error`, but for to whom may be interested, here is the details:

```
name:0x7fffffffdce8 "И\277UUU"
message:0x5555555d6fbd <handler::handler(std::span<door, 18446744073709551615ul>)+191> "\220H\213E\350dH+\004%("
_need_free:1439044320
```

- I have checked the literal strings using D-Feet app and everything seems to be right.
- I've tried running as root or without root.
- I've tried adding the user to bluetooth group.

What is wrong with this code?

[source code of sd_bus_set_property](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/libsystemd/sd-bus/bus-convenience.c) shows that internally, it calls "Set" from "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties". Most of the bluetooth examples I've seen, do this without using "sd_bus_set_property", but I'm curious to see how it can be done via "sd_bus_set_property".

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I built systemd from source and stepped into its functions and saw at some point it checks the error and since it's not null, returns.

```
sd_bus_error sd_error = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
```

fixed the issue.